# Visual Studio Code in Linux - Remap F5 (Debug) from "dotnet build" to "msbuild csproj"?

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, mono, visual-studio-code

I tried building a C# project in Visual Studio (VS) Code in Ubuntu Linux, but the default build (F5 Debug) always runs the command "dotnet build". This in turn does not work because within my csproj file (Project.csproj), I'm using the following setting:

```html
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

This in turn tries to build every csproj file in the directory (which I only want to build one) and it also fails to build each one on .NETFramework v4.5, producing the following error:

*/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.2/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1122,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of referenceassemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.*

I've found a workaround by downloading and installing Mono, then NuGet, then using this command from Mono in the VS Code TERMINAL window:

```
jbrumbaugh@jbrumbaugh-VirtualBox:~/Dropbox/.../Project$ msbuild Project.csproj
```

This command successfully creates a working EXE within the bin/debug folder.

My problem is I cannot actually use the VS Code debugger to hit breakpoints and step through code. Is there a way I can modify the settings within VS Code or some csproj file to successfully reroute the .NET framework to that used by Mono, or substitute the default debug build command with one that I specify?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure what the F5 command does in a few different ways.

The easiest way is to modify the pre-launch task. This is found in the file `"${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/tasks.json`. By default, the F5 command runs the task labeled `build`, which by default is set to run `dotnet build`. You can customize the task by editing the `command` and `args` fields. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks for more info.

Another thing you could do is remap what F5 does. By default it runs the `workbench.action.debug.start` command. You can remap this by going to the menu **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts**. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings for more info.